# MYSQL внешние ключи

Tags: mysql

Прочел про внешние ключи MYSQL 7 статей и так и не понял.
Почему не понял - не нашел ответа на вопрос:
Предположим у нас есть таблицы

1. Бренд(`brand`){`id`(PRYMARY,AOUTOINCREMENT),`name`(VARCHAR 300)}
2. Модель(`model`){`id`(PRYMARY,AOUToINCREMENT),`name`(VARCHAR 300),`brand_id`(INT)}
3. Заказ(`order`){`id`(PRYMARY,AOUTOINCREMENT),`model_id`(INT),`count`(INT)}

**Делаем ключи:**

- в таблице `model` ключу `brand_id` делаем - `brand`.`id` ON DELETE CASCADE (этим мы говорим: удалить все модели удаляемого бренда)
- также проделываем в таблице `order` ключу `model_id` - `model`.`id` ON DELETE RESTRICT(этим мы говорим не удалять модель, если за ней закреплены заказ(ы) )

**Вопрос:**

1. Что будет если в таблице `brand` удалить Бренд, у которого есть модели и одна из этих моделей есть в заказе?

Comment: Запрос завершиться с ошибкой. весь целиком, ничего не удалится

Comment: Спс @Mike - теперь все стало понятно

Comment: открывайте консоль и пробуйте, не стесняйтесь - быстрее и веселее чем написать вопрос и ждать на него ответа ))